# Existing MVC website - integrating Telerik MVC Grid to use ServerSideEditing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, renderpartial, actionresult

I have an existing MVC site, built some years back, and I am now removing all my custom grid code with Telerik's MVC  Grid.

I wish to utilise the ServerSide editing but the examples show the SourceCodeFile scaffolding on a single control actionresult reference by a single MVC grid in a single view.

My issue is that I have mulitple MVC grids called by renderpartial in a single view with a single controller actionresult.  I cannot have multiple scaffolding on the single actionresult.

I therefore need some assistance on thinking this through as I only visit this project once in a while and I am not constantly building in MVC so do not totally know all my options.

Also posted on the Telerik forums at: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/existing-mvc-website---integrating-telerik-mvc-grid-to-use-serversideediting.aspx

Comment: Can you post two of ur girds how they look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingserverside), you will see that for each grid, you can specify the action/controller to execute for each action (select, insert, update, delete).  If I am understanding you correctly, you should then be able to manage editing of each grid server side, correct?